# Which code is executed when generating .sty from .dtx?

Tags: package-writing, dtx, doc

I am trying to understand how to generate `.sty` using `.dtx`. Suppose I want the following code to be in the `.sty` file:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{ }{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bar}{ }{}
\ifluatex
  \let\baz\foo
\else
  \let\baz\bar
\fi
```

I am trying to do it in the following way:

```
%\begin{macro}{\foo}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{ }{}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
%\begin{macro}{\bar}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bar}{ }{}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
\ifluatex
  \let\baz\foo
\else
  \let\baz\bar
\fi
```

But I get two errors: `! LaTeX cmd Error: Command '\bar' already defined.` and `! Undefined control sequence. l.25 \ifluatex`

As I understand, this happens because the code is executed, while I just want it to appear in the `.sty` in `.pdf`.

Complete MWE:

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\expandafter\begingroup
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\usedir{./}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\expandafter\endgroup
%</internal>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{\jobname}
\usepackage[numbered]{hypdoc}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
    \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
%\begin{macro}{\foo}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{ }{}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
%\begin{macro}{\bar}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bar}{ }{}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
\ifluatex
  \let\baz\foo
\else
  \let\baz\bar
\fi
%\Finale
```

Comment: presumably \ifluatex
  \let\baz\foo
\else
  \let\baz\bar
\fi is intended for the package so should be in macrocode

Comment: what is the intention of the group here? `\expandafter\endgroup` the expandafter is acting on `\documentclass` ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you want `tex mypac.dtx` to act as an install file and extract `mypac.sty` and `pdflatex mypac.dtx` to typeset the documentation.

```
% \iffalse
%<*switch>
\ifx\documentclass\undefined
%</switch>
%<*ins>
\input docstrip
\generate{\file{mypac.sty}{\from{mypac.dtx}{package}}}
\expandafter\endbatchfile
%</ins>
%<*switch>
\fi
%</switch>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{doc}
\begin{document}
\title{The \textsf{mypac} package}
\DocInput{mypac.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
%
%\begin{macro}{\foo}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{ }{}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
%\begin{macro}{\bar}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bar}{ }{}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
%\begin{macro}{\baz}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\ifluatex
  \let\baz\foo
\else
  \let\baz\bar
\fi
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
```

Producing

[image]

with `pdflatex` and

```
%%
%% This is file `mypac.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% mypac.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% 
%% IMPORTANT NOTICE:
%% 
%% For the copyright see the source file.
%% 
%% Any modified versions of this file must be renamed
%% with new filenames distinct from mypac.sty.
%% 
%% For distribution of the original source see the terms
%% for copying and modification in the file mypac.dtx.
%% 
%% This generated file may be distributed as long as the
%% original source files, as listed above, are part of the
%% same distribution. (The sources need not necessarily be
%% in the same archive or directory.)
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{ }{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bar}{ }{}
\ifluatex
  \let\baz\foo
\else
  \let\baz\bar
\fi
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `mypac.sty'.
```

with `tex mypac.dtx`

Comment: I think there was a copy-paste mistake for the `.dtx` code? It is now the same as the `.sty`.

Comment: @Marijn oops, thanks for the note:-) I'll fix

Comment: Can you please explain what does `<switch>` tag do?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman it is an arbitrary name that is not `package` (I forgot that guard with the first post) You can remove the four `switch`  guards and it still works but the unguarded `\ifx\documentclass\undefined\fi` would "fall through" and end up in the generated .sty which is harmless but pointless test. Guarding it with anything means it is not copied by the `\generate{\file{mypac.sty}{\from{mypac.dtx}{package}}}`  Note this (and the ifx tricks) are only needed so that the same dtx can be used (with plain tex) as a `.ins` file, rather than say `tools.ins` as we do in latex-tools

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, I see. So everything that is unguarded or guarded by `<package>` ends up in the `sty`? Also, I have a problem with generating `readme` file: I get the code of the package itself in the file. Would you be king to help with that?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman  You could guard the readme with `%<*readme>...%</readme>` and use `\generate{\file{readme.txt}{\from{mypac.dtx}{readme}}}` But are you sure you want to do that? CTAN (and github/gitlab/etc) need a `readme.txt`  as a separate file, a readme is "quick help for a user" it isn't normally something that the user would need to extract

Comment: @DavidCarlisle okay, I see, thank you